# Jackson+JAXB in rest-assured

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, rest-assured

I need to serialize my POJO object that relies on JAXB annotations. I can easily do this with Jackson (adding `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`). Is possible without any explicit coding?

It would be really nice to write it fluently akin to this:

```
port(Integer.valueOf(port)).
            log().all().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            body(criteria, ObjectMapperType.JACKSON_2)
```

Yet this one ignores JAXB. I want to find some neat and clean solution. Jackson + JAXB is very common practice, it will be such a shame if RestAssured is not equipped with it under the hood. I found something like this on the forum:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(
new Jackson2ObjectMapperFactory() {
        @Override
        public ObjectMapper create(Class aClass, String s) {
            FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(...);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setFilters(filter);
            return objectMapper;
        }
    }
));
```

but this will be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common use case please add it as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/list) and I'll try to integrate it as default.

Comment: Johan, I'm not talking about a default configuration, but this one is pretty common. Can you add a mapper like ObjectMapperType.JACKSON_2_JAXB or something like that. A default one, in my opinion, should use Jackson annotations, the one I want should be just optional. Should I create an issue?

Comment: Please try the latest snapshot, 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT and see if it has been resolved. See https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/snapshot for more details. If not then please add an issue.

Comment: Ok, I played around with it. Looks good. Thanks, Johan! When can we expect to see a release?

Comment: Not sure.. Currently nothing is changed in 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT except this tiny change so it should be safe to use.

Comment: The behaviour we are talking about is quite basic. Today I checked our other service written in Spring+Camel+CXF and this is exactly how it works. With your latest SNAPSHOT update my rest-assured client can properly communicate with my Spring+Camel+CXF server, yet when I switch back to 2.4.0, the communication fails. The reason is that the client and the server both use the same DTOs, but the way these DTOs are marshaled by the server is not understood by the rest-assured client based on 2.4.0. Any rought estimate about the next release?

Comment: I assume based on the fact that the comment was almost 8 years ago that perhaps this has been released ;)